# Confused by regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

So I am trying to use Googles regexextract

```
A1B2-DHSJDH472847XXX-FJDN REV : W25
```

I've tried:

```
Regexextract (A1,"^(?: .{4}-).*(?:\s).*$")
```

This just gives me the entire string and still capture the non capturing group to be matched.

Expected result:`DHSJDH472847XXX-FJDN`

Comment: the minus sign(-) maybe the culprit here. Once check if you remove it then are you able to get some of your functionality back?

Comment: you may use minus sign as [-] for matching in regex

Comment: is the space before `.{4}` intended? your regex does not match anything from your example if i don't add a space before it

Comment: What are you trying to capture?

Comment: @mfizz In other words, what is the expected result? What is static, and what is dynamic? To grab the `A1B2-DHSJDH472847XXX-FJDN` code, you may use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^\S+")`. To grab `REV : W25`, use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1," +(.*)")`

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected result. Removing "-" yields the same result. space.{4} was not intended but the result is the entire string still.

Comment: @mfizz I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `REGEXEXTRACT` either returns the whole match if there are no *capturing* groups in the pattern and only capturing group contents if a capturing group is defined in the pattern. Your `^(?: .{4}-).*(?:\s).*$` pattern matches the whole string without capturing any part, thus, it does not work as expected. Note that non-capturing groups without quantifiers set on them or without any alternation operators are redundant. `(?:\s)` is equal to `\s`.

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A20,"^[^-]*-(\S+)")
```

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]*`  - 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `(\S+)` - capturing group 1 (the text matched with this group will be the output, the rest will be omitted) that matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars.